# No on click function

Tags: oracle-jet

I am working on bubble chart in oracle jet.If I click on any bubble it should generate a new bubble chart.I don't know how to do it,moreover there's no on click function in it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking better received questions. Please add your code along with error messages/logs so people can see what you tried and what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable "drilling" option and then use "drill" event to handle clicks. Read more in the JS Doc at:

> http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojChart.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-bind to bind the click handler of the bubble chart.

```
<div data-bind="click: onClick, ojComponent: {component: 'ojChart',
type:'bubble'}">
</div>
```

And then in your model declaration define a method onClick() where you can write the implementation